# Simple Karma + Typescript configuration - Reference Error: x is not defined

Tags: typescript, karma-runner

I'd like to set up a basic test runner using Karma to test a Typescript class.

When I run the tests `karma start`, I'm getting the error `ReferenceError: Calculator is not defined.` Presumably, the karma runner probably does not import the transpiled source or the preprocessor does not transpile the source.

My source is [here in a repo](https://github.com/monkeyhouse/KarmaTypescriptConfigQuestion) with revant parts below. How can I get the configuration to work / what am I missing?

My current understanding is that the transpiler and karma 'files' configuration property will load the calculator class for me.

```
transpiler => lib/calculator.ts => lib/calculator.ts
files => okay, loading lib/**/.js
```

/lib/calclulator.ts

```
export class Calculator{
  add ( a : number , b : number) : number {
    return a + b;
  } 
}
```

/test/calculator.test.js

```
describe('Demo Test Runner', function() {
  var calc = new Calculator();
  it('should return 3 for 1 + 2', function() {
   expect( calc.add(1,2) ).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

package.json

```
...
"devDependencies": {
  "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
  "karma": "^1.3.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
  "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
  "karma-typescript-preprocessor": "^0.3.0"
}
```

karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
 config.set({

 ...
 frameworks: ['jasmine'],

 files: [
    'lib/**/*.js',
    'test/**/*.js'
  ],


 preprocessors: {
   '**/*.ts': ['typescript']         
 },


 typescriptPreprocessor: {
    // options passed to the typescript compiler 
    options: {
      sourceMap: true, // (optional) Generates corresponding .map file. 
      target: 'ES5', // (optional) Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), or 'ES5' 
      module: 'amd', // (optional) Specify module code generation: 'commonjs' or 'amd' 
      noImplicitAny: true, // (optional) Warn on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. 
      noResolve: true, // (optional) Skip resolution and preprocessing. 
      removeComments: true, // (optional) Do not emit comments to output. 
      concatenateOutput: false // (optional) Concatenate and emit output to single file. By default true if module option is omited, otherwise false. 
    },
    // transforming the filenames 
    transformPath: function(path) {
      return path.replace(/\.ts$/, '.js');
    }
 }
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you define calculator as

```
export class Calculator{...}
```

This means that your `/lib/calculator.ts` is a module and it's classes need to be imported by other modules for them to be visible (they are not global).

So your `/test/calculator.test.js` needs to import this module somehow. How to do this would depend on what your module configuration in your `tsconfig.json`

In your case you would probably want to use either `"module" : "commonjs"` or `"module": "amd"`.

However, you will need an additional plugin for karma to be able to load these modules. If you use `amd` then something like `karma-requirejs`, if you use `commonjs` you might need something like `karma-webpack`. And you would then need to use the syntax necessary to import it in your js file (e.g. `var MyCalculator = require('/lib/calculator');`)

Your other alternative is to not "export" your `Calculator` class. That would make it globally available. However, you should really try to get the module way to work as that is the recommended approach in larger applications.