# Setting up karma typescript configuration

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

I am generating a sample angular project based on the generator provided [here](https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library)

I would like to run tests on a typescript class as a standalone service, I have created a karma config that makes uses of the `karma-typescript` preprocessor and the `jasmine` framework. When I run the tests, I get an error messaage that looks  like this:

```
Chrome 55.0.2883 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught Error: Can't find ./util/fixtures [undefined] (required by /home/vamsi/Do/library-project/src/glist.service.spec.ts)
  at node_modules/karma-typescript/lib/commonjs.js:13
```

This is my `tsconfig`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "index.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictMetadataEmit": true
  }
}
```

This is my `karma.conf.js` which is based on the configuration provided for Angular2 [here](https://github.com/monounity/karma-typescript)

I have tried to add all my files to the `files` in the karma configuration  as well as provide a

```
compilerOptions: {
   module: 'commonjs'
}
```

in the `karma.conf.js` as sugggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40329173/simple-karma-typescript-configuration-reference-error-x-is-not-defined).

What is the best possible way of getting unit tests setup for the project for testing components and services using karma?